# 'You should find replacements for the following formulae: ilmbase' and 'Refusing to uninstall ilmbase because it is required by vcs'

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew

Brew doctor shows me:

```
Warning: Some installed formulae are deprecated or disabled.
You should find replacements for the following formulae:
  ilmbase
```

Because I don't know the package `ilmbase` and didn't find much info with Brave Search about it, I tried:

```
brew uninstall --zap ilmbase
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/ilmbase/2.5.7
because it is required by vcs, which is currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ilmbase
```

`vcs` is a package I wish to keep and use.

But in `vcs` there seems no `ilmbase` dependency? See `==> Dependencies` list.

```
brew info vcs
vcs: stable 1.13.4 (bottled)
Creates video contact sheets (previews) of videos
https://p.outlyer.net/vcs/
/usr/local/Cellar/vcs/1.13.4_3 (12 files, 249.2KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-01-08 at 16:56:55
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/vcs.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: ffmpeg ✔, ghostscript ✔, gnu-getopt ✔, imagemagick ✔
==> Analytics
install: 61 (30 days), 150 (90 days), 983 (365 days)
install-on-request: 60 (30 days), 149 (90 days), 976 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

What's wrong here? Is this a bug? How to get rid of `ilmbase`, but keep `vcs`?

Answer (score 7):

I also got this message while running `brew doctor`. It seems `ilmbase` was previously installed because ImageMagick (among other libraries) relied on it. The [`ilmbase` formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/028894637d096471c531f9a860c7eadb42cab102/Formula/ilmbase.rb#L20-L21) reveals that [the `ilmbase` library has since been renamed/replaced by the OpenEXR library](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr/pull/929).

If you are getting errors when trying to remove `ilmbase` or are seeing packages that still rely on it, consider running `brew update` and then `brew upgrade` to resolve any potential outdated dependency references. Also consider running `brew doctor` again in case that reveals any relevant information.

After updating and upgrading, I verified that nothing relied on `ilmbase`:

```
brew uses --installed ilmbase
```

And then uninstalled it:

```
brew uninstall ilmbase
```

You can also verify whether or not the updated versions of your library (e.g. ImageMagick) are using OpenEXR:

```
brew deps --installed imagemagick
brew uses --installed openexr
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well but, I updated xcode-tools and then did...

```
brew upgrade ilmbase
```

This resolved my issue.